# Can we restrict Users from accessing Office 365 from certain IP address

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure

we have office 365 tenant and our team over in india actively uses that for day to day stuff. But now we only want to allow users to access Office 365 from there office network. can we do that in Office 365.

When users login from other IP address other than office network it would simply block the access.

Answer (score 3):

Check **Set a location-based policy in the new SharePoint admin center** in office guideline below.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/control-access-based-on-network-location#set-a-location-based-policy-in-the-new-sharepoint-admin-center

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure Conditional Access](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview) to restrict access to your O365 resouces.

Using this feature requires an Azure AD Premium P1 license though.

[image]